# Vertically center <a> tag?

Tags: html, css, positioning

I'm struggling to vertically centre  tag in of of the elements.

What I've got is something like:

http://jsbin.com/arudif/2/edit

```
<style>
 header {padding: 20px 0 20px 0; clear: both;}
 header a {
   float: right;
   vertical-align: middle; 
   margin: auto 0 auto 0;
   } 
   //This is what I tried, doesnt work
</style>

<header>
   <a href="#">Center Me Please!</a>
   <p> Stack Overflow </p>
</header>
```

I just can't figure auto ho to fix that  tag in the header

Comment: @MarcB Hi that Didn't work for me ;/

Comment: Vertically Center it according to what? There's a paragraph under it, that paragraph can be 1 line or 10000 line, do you want absolute centering?

Comment: @AliBassam I guess I do mean absolute centring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To Center `a` without taking in consideration the other contents of the container, use absolute positioning.

```
header
{
    position:relative;
}
a
{
    position:absolute;
    top: 50%; // nearly 50%, but not exactly 50%
    left: 50%;
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work if you have multiple a tags inside multiple divs, like in a navbar, and most of the situations. the a tags just overlap each other due to absolute positioning.

Answer (score 7):

Just add a line-height property to your anchor rule that adds up to the padding of the container and margin of the paragraph: `line-height : 50px;`

http://jsfiddle.net/HS6Lp/

Comment: line-heigh is not an option as there is more than one line of text: http://jsbin.com/arudif/2/edit

Comment: Not according to your question and example. My answer solves your question. If you want specific answers that accommodate all hurdles, you need to disclose those hurdles in your question.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way using display:table; and display:table-cell;. I've added a height to the div to show it does actually center. Also removed your float as it will conflict with the aligning.

```
<div>
   <a href="#">Center Me Please!</a>
   <p> Stack Overflow </p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {padding: 20px 0 20px 0; clear: both;background:green;display:table;height:200px;}
div a {
display:table-cell;
   vertical-align: middle; 
   margin: auto 0 auto 0;
   }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LR6rz/

Comment: didn't work http://jsbin.com/arudif/2/edit

Comment: It does work, as my example shows (http://jsfiddle.net/LR6rz/). It doesn't work in your example because you've kept float:right; which I said will conflict.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the parent `header` to use centered text and auto side margins. You then set the `p` tag to use left aligned text.

```
<style>
header {
  padding: 20px 0 20px 0; 
  clear: both;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto 0 auto 0; 
}
header a {

}
header p {
   text-align: left;
}
</style>

<header>
   <a href="#">Center Me Please!</a>
   <p> Stack Overflow </p>
</header>
```

Depending on your use case you can set the auto side margins on just the `a` tag allowing you to use different margins on the `header` tag.

See http://codepen.io/alienresident/pen/fgkvc to play around with code.